# How to add working filters for max_sale_qty and manage_stock in Product grid in Magento 2.3?

Tags: attributes, grid, filter, magento2.3.5

I am trying to add working filters for `max_sale_qty` and `manage_stock` in product grid in Magento 2.3. I got the columns **Max Sale Qty** and **Manage Stock** in product grid to display the records using `addField()` methods and `dataSource/dataProvider`. But I couldn't get the filters to work though. I am fairly new to Magento and couldn't get the filters to work after hours of looking up online.

How do I get these filters working? Thanks.

Here is my code (All the required module files are given):

VendorName/ProductMaxSaleQty/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">

    <!-- datasource that has a dataprovider -->
    <dataSource name="product_listing_data_source" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider">
      
        <settings>
            <storageConfig>
                <param name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">filters.store_id</param>
            </storageConfig>
            <updateUrl path="mui/index/render"/>
        </settings>

        <aclResource>Magento_Catalog::products</aclResource>


        <!-- dataprovider -->
        <dataProvider class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider" name="product_listing_data_source">

            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>entity_id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>

        </dataProvider>

    </dataSource>


    <!-- defining the columns -->
    <columns name="product_columns">

        <column name="manage_stock" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select" sortOrder="76">
                <settings>
                    <addField>true</addField>
                    <options class="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno"/>
                    <filter>select</filter>
                    <dataType>select</dataType>
                    <sortable>false</sortable>
                    <label translate="true">Managed Stock</label>
                </settings>
           </column>

        <column name="max_sale_qty" sortOrder="77">
            <settings>
                <addField>true</addField>
                <filter>textRange</filter>
                <label translate="true">Max Sale Qty</label>
            </settings>
        </column>

    </columns>

</listing>
```

VendorName/ProductMaxSaleQty/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider">
        <arguments>

            <argument name="addFieldStrategies" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="max_sale_qty" xsi:type="object">VendorName\ProductMaxSaleQty\Ui\DataProvider\Product\AddMaxSaleQtyFieldToCollection</item>
            </argument>
            <argument name="addFilterStrategies" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="max_sale_qty" xsi:type="object">VendorName\ProductMaxSaleQty\Ui\DataProvider\Product\AddMaxSaleQtyFilterToCollection</item>
            </argument>

            <argument name="addFieldStrategies" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="manage_stock" xsi:type="object">VendorName\ProductMaxSaleQty\Ui\DataProvider\Product\AddManageStockFieldToCollection</item>
            </argument>
            <argument name="addFilterStrategies" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="manage_stock" xsi:type="object">VendorName\ProductMaxSaleQty\Ui\DataProvider\Product\AddManageStockFilterToCollection</item>
            </argument>

        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

VendorName/ProductMaxSaleQty/Ui/DataProvider/Product/AddManageStockFieldToCollection.php

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ProductMaxSaleQty\Ui\DataProvider\Product;

class AddManageStockFieldToCollection implements \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AddFieldToCollectionInterface
{
    public function addField(\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $collection, $field, $alias = null)
    {
        $collection->joinField('manage_stock', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'manage_stock', 'product_id=entity_id', null, 'left');
    }
}
```

VendorName/ProductMaxSaleQty/Ui/DataProvider/Product/AddManageStockFilterToCollection.php

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ProductMaxSaleQty\Ui\DataProvider\Product;

class AddManageStockFilterToCollection implements \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AddFilterToCollectionInterface
{

    public function addFilter(\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $collection, $field, $condition = null)
    {
        if (isset($condition['eq'])) {
            $collection->addFieldToFilter($field, $condition);

        }                   
    } 
}
```

VendorName/ProductMaxSaleQty/Ui/DataProvider/Product/AddMaxSaleQtyFieldToCollection.php

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ProductMaxSaleQty\Ui\DataProvider\Product;

class AddMaxSaleQtyFieldToCollection implements \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AddFieldToCollectionInterface
{
    public function addField(\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $collection, $field, $alias = null)
    {
        $collection->joinField('max_sale_qty', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'max_sale_qty', 'product_id=entity_id', null, 'left');
    }
}
```

VendorName/ProductMaxSaleQty/Ui/DataProvider/Product/AddMaxSaleQtyFilterToCollection.php

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ProductMaxSaleQty\Ui\DataProvider\Product;

use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable\Attribute\Collection as AttributesCollection;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection;
use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AddFilterToCollectionInterface;

class AddMaxSaleQtyFilterToCollection implements \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AddFilterToCollectionInterface
{
    public function addFilter(\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $collection, $field, $condition = null)
    {
        if (isset($condition['eq'])) {
            $collection->addFieldToFilter($field, $condition);
        }
    }
}
```

VendorName/ProductMaxSaleQty/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="VendorName_ProductMaxSaleQty" setup_version="0.0.1">
    <sequence>
      <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
    </sequence>
  </module>
</config>
```

VendorName/ProductMaxSaleQty/registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'VendorName_ProductMaxSaleQty',
    __DIR__
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the logic inside these files make it not work.

Pls try changing them as following;

VendorName/ProductMaxSaleQty/Ui/DataProvider/Product/AddManageStockFilterToCollection.php

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ProductMaxSaleQty\Ui\DataProvider\Product;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class AddManageStockFilterToCollection implements \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AddFilterToCollectionInterface
{

    public function addFilter(\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $collection, $field, $condition = null)
    {
//        if (isset($condition['eq'])) {
//            $collection->addFieldToFilter($field, $condition);
//
//        }

//        if (isset($condition['in'])) {
//            $collection->getSelect()->where(
//                AbstractCollection::ATTRIBUTE_TABLE_ALIAS_PREFIX .  'qty.manage_stock IN (?)',
//                implode($condition['in'])
//            );
//        }

        if (isset($condition['eq'])) {
                $collection->getSelect()->where(
                    AbstractCollection::ATTRIBUTE_TABLE_ALIAS_PREFIX . 'qty.manage_stock = ?',
                    (float)$condition['eq']
                );
        }
    }
}
```

VendorName/ProductMaxSaleQty/Ui/DataProvider/Product/AddMaxSaleQtyFilterToCollection.php

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ProductMaxSaleQty\Ui\DataProvider\Product;

use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable\Attribute\Collection as AttributesCollection;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection;
use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AddFilterToCollectionInterface;

class AddMaxSaleQtyFilterToCollection implements \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AddFilterToCollectionInterface
{
    public function addFilter(\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $collection, $field, $condition = null)
    {
//        if (isset($condition['eq'])) {
//            $collection->addFieldToFilter($field, $condition);
//        }
        if (isset($condition['gteq'])) {
            $collection->getSelect()->where(
                AbstractCollection::ATTRIBUTE_TABLE_ALIAS_PREFIX . 'qty.max_sale_qty >= ?',
                (float)$condition['gteq']
            );
        }
        if (isset($condition['lteq'])) {
            $collection->getSelect()->where(
                AbstractCollection::ATTRIBUTE_TABLE_ALIAS_PREFIX . 'qty.max_sale_qty <= ?',
                (float)$condition['lteq']
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Filter for `max_sale_qty` is now working, cheers! But `manage_stock` filter was previously not working, no errors. I used xdebug to find out its yes/no dropdown is sending 1/0 and made few changes to the filter code to get it working. Modified your answer with my code and everything works now. Please review and accept my edit. Cheers.

Comment: @RajaP what happens if both Yes and No options are selected, was just curios, I couldn't check it after your fix though

Comment: The `manage_stock` filter I have added in `product_listing.xml` is a dropdown selector and since being not a multiselector one cannot select both Yes and No, so no issues there :)